# Is there a way to autocorrect spellings in solr and return additional fields corresponding to corrected value?

Tags: solr, autocomplete, spell-checking, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I have used suggester component in SOLR but I feel its more limited due to the fact that I lose control over the values and the fields (if I am in interested in getting back other fields along with my corrected spelling).

I am currently using shingles and edgengram filter factory for position free autosuggest and I specify the required fields to be returned along with autosuggest list.

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" /> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramIfNoNgram="true" maxShingleSize="99"/>
        <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Is there a way to use suggester or any other component in SOLR (or any other filter) to return autosuggest results, perform inline correction and also return desired field in response?

**Note:**
I was looking in to fuse.js and I really like the way the autocorrection works there. Its not a server side autocorrection though but uses Bitmap algorithm for approximate string matching.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to get?

Comment: For example: If someone types in 'ipad ari' in autosuggest I am trying to do auto correction (to 'ipad air') based on specific field and return the documents where that specific field has complete content 'ipad air'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do on the fly autosuggest using combination of spell check component and the above code logic.

First I check if the spelling is correct (using spell check component), if I dont get any suggestion back I just try to query with original keyword. If i get any suggestion back, I use the suggested term (collation) for new query.